# How to install Python3.6 on Redhat 7.4 Server using epel?

Tags: python-3.x, redhat, epel

I have always used below mentioned commands to install Python3.6 on redhat 7.4 server
I have mounted the server with iso file and placed some additional packages locally on my server.

Python installation on RedHat 7.4:

```
yum install gcc
yum install openssl-devel
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel
yum install mysql-devel gcc gcc-devel
rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y python36-setuptools
sudo easy_install-3.6 pip
yum search python3 | grep devel
yum install python36-devel.x86_64
python3 (# to verify python installed or not)
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Now i am unable to install Python3.6 using these commands. Servers shows an error that there is no package available `python36-setuptools`

How can i install Python3.6?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 is available for RHEL 7 as a [Software Collection](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/updates). Use the installation instructions [here](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world#fndtn-python).